# How can the linear combination of infinite normalized Klein-Gordon fields be a normalizable field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, regularization, normalization

In the context of a Klein-Gordon field with charge $e$, mass $m$, immersed in an external classical electric field $A_\mu = (A_0(z), 0)$, I am asked to calculate the charge density of the field solution to the 1+1 dimensional Klein-Gordon Equation
$$(D_\mu D^\mu + m) \phi (t, z) = 0,$$
with $D_\mu = \partial_\mu + ie A_\mu$ and using Dirichlet boundary conditions $\phi(0) = \phi(1) = 0$.

With the ansatz $\phi_n(t, z) = \phi_n(z)e^{-i\omega_n}$, the PDE turns into an ODE, and the solution can be expressed as a linear combination of each mode
$$ \phi(t, z) = \sum_{n>0}a_n \phi_n(z) e^{-i\omega_n t} + \sum_{n<0} b_n^\dagger \phi_n(z) e^{i\omega_n t},$$
with $[a_n, a_m^\dagger] = \delta_{nm}$, $[b_n, b_m^\dagger] = \delta_{nm}$, and all other commutators vanishing.

The problem arises when trying to calculate the charge density $\rho$ of the solution.
$$\rho = j_0 = ie \langle \Omega\rvert  (\phi^* D_0 \phi - \phi D_0^* \phi^*) \lvert\Omega\rangle,$$
assuming a normalized vacuum state $\lvert \Omega\rangle$, the only surviving terms after multiplication will be those of the form $$\langle \Omega \rvert a_n a_n^\dagger \lvert\phi\rvert^2 (\omega_n - e A_0(z)) \lvert \Omega \rangle = \langle \Omega \rvert ([a_n, a_n^\dagger] + 1) \lvert\phi\rvert^2  (\omega_n - e A_0(z)) \lvert \Omega \rangle =  (\omega_n - e A_0(z)) \lvert\phi\rvert^2.$$
The time dependency drops in each term when multiplying each mode with its complex conjugate, since $e^{-i (\omega_n - \omega_m}) \delta_{mn} = 1$.
Thus, the density charge can be expressed as the sum of contribution to the density from each mode,
$$ \rho(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=\infty}(\omega_n - e A_0(z)) \lvert\phi_n\rvert^2. $$

We are now seeing an infinite series of a sequence of normalized functions. How on Earth can this series be finite? We are adding up a sequence that is not necessarily tending to zero, how can this turn out to be finite?

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your expression for $\rho$ you have $\vert \phi\vert^2$ where I would expect $\vert \phi_n\vert^2$. And do you maybe know anything about these $\phi_n$ and/or the $\omega_n$? The former should definitely tend to zero quickly for your ansatz for $\phi$ itself to make sense.

Comment: @unsure you are right, I changed it. On $\phi_n$ having to tend quickly to zero, that was what I wanted my question to be, sorry if it was worded poorly. What I do not understand is; how can the $\phi_n$ tend to zero if they are normalized?
When dealing with a QM system, a general solution would be something like $\sum a_n \phi_n$, so normalizabilty comes from the $a_n$. Here we do not have any $a_n$. That is what I do not understand.

Comment: I don't think the individual $\phi_n$ are normalized to 1. $\phi$ is a field, not a wavefunction. It doesn't have to be normalized as a function. Maybe it makes sense to normalize $\langle\Omega\vert \phi^* \phi\vert \Omega\rangle$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I think that is exactly what I was overlooking. What actually needs to be normalized is indeed $(\omega_n - e A_0(z))\lvert \phi_n \rvert ^2$ but that still gives me troubles. Maybe the problem is purely computational.

Comment: No, no. Actually the fact that the $  ⟨Ω|∗|Ω⟩ = (\omega_n - e A_0(z))\lvert \phi \rvert^2$  are normalized troubles me even further. If we are adding an infinite amount of these terms, for these series to converge the terms must oscillate in a VERY specific fashion. How can that converge??

Answer (score 0):

This is what Hadamard States and Point Split normalization are for. The product of two distributions ($\phi^*(x)\phi(x)$) is a priori not defined. Not only that, but the two point functions $$ w(x, x') = \langle \Omega \rvert \phi(x)^* \phi(x') \lvert \Omega \rangle$$ are usually proportional to $\delta(x-x')$. It's easy to see why it would be divergent as $x' \to x$.

To ensure convergence when taking the limit, one must apply the $i\varepsilon $ prescription $t' = t + \tau + i\varepsilon$. This way
$$\langle \Omega \rvert \phi(x)^* D_0 \phi(x') \lvert \Omega \rangle = - i \sum_{n>0} \lvert \phi(z)\rvert^2 (\omega_n - eA_0(z)) e^{-i\omega_n (\tau +i\varepsilon)}, $$ and thus

$$ \rho(z) = \langle \Omega \rvert \phi(x)^* D_0 \phi(x') - \phi(x) D_0^* \phi^*(x')\lvert \Omega \rangle = $$
$$ =e \lim_{\tau\to 0} \left( \sum_{n>0} \lvert \phi(z) \rvert^2 (\omega_n - A_0) e^{-i\omega_n (\tau + i\varepsilon)} + \lvert \phi(z) \rvert^2 (\omega_n - A_0) e^{i\omega_n (\tau + i\varepsilon)} \right) + \frac{e^2}{\pi}A_0(z),$$
which does converge (sometimes).